# chrome.history.deleteUrl not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just tried `chrome.history.deleteURL` in an HTML page and it's not working. Can anyone say where I am going wrong?

Urls.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your History</title>
        <style>
            body {min-width: 300px;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/Javascript">
            function deleteURL(form){
                var urlName = form.url.value;
                chrome.history.deleteUrl(urlName);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onSubmit="deleteURL(this);">
            Enter url here : <input type="text" name="url" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Browser History",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Shows up the history",
    "permissions": [
        "history",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "Urls.html",
        "default_icon": "history.jpg"
    }
}
```

After executing the program I can still see the URL which I wanted to delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I have never used the [chrome.history.*](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html) API before your code looks like it should work.

Have you remembered to add the required permission to your [manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#manifest)?

**Edit:**

Doh! I just realised that your API call is invalid. Try using this updated version of the `deleteUrl` function;

```
function deleteURL(form){
    chrome.history.deleteUrl({
        url: form.url.value
    });
}
```

Notice that I've wrapped the argument in an object with a `url` property [as per the API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#method-deleteUrl). Don't know why I didn't see that earlier.

Comment: Yes. I have added. I have updated question by adding manifest file also

Comment: @freepublicview Please see my updated answer as I spotted something obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Oh i messed up in understanding that API. Thanks

Comment: @freepublicview No problem. It's worth remembering that *most* [chrome.* API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) functions used objects as their parameters as it makes future changes easier and is much cleaner by design. Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: I did't work for me 

`chrome.history.deleteUrl({url: weburl});`